# Numpy - Find occurrences of elements in 1d array within a 2d array

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

I'm battling to fix the following piece of code:

```
import numpy as np

arr1 = np.array([2,15,132,135,136])
arr2 = np.array([[0,0,0,0,0], [2,15,132,307,406], [15,132,135,136,148]])

s1 = np.sum(np.all(arr1 == arr2[:, None], axis=1), axis=1)
print(s1)
```

The result I'm expecting is `[0 3 4]`, to show that:

1. There were no matches found in arr2 for row index 0
2. Three matches were found in arr2 for row index 1
3. Four matches were found in arr2 for row index 2

The actual result I get is `[0 3 0]`

Can someone please help me to make sense of this and assist me to modify the code to yield the desired result?

Comment: The answer by Reti43 is looking solid; and is probably optimal for small arrays. But are you interested in scalability to larger arrays at all?

Comment: @EelcoHoogendoorn I am intrigued by the scalability potential as I can't think of another approach right now. I wouldn't mind seeing an answer (and it could help future readers), or at least a link where said approach is utilised.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> (arr1 == arr2[...,None]).sum(axis=(1, 2))
array([0, 3, 4])
```

You want to broadcast for the last axis of `arr2`. By using the colon instead of the ellipsis, you add the new axis after the first one.

```
>>> arr2[:,None].shape
(3, 1, 5)
>>> arr2[...,None].shape   # arr2[:,:,None] would also work
(3, 5, 1)
```

Comment: @EelcoHoogendoorn - I've tested the given code, and it works fine for however many rows in the 2d array. Since the 2d array will only be about 5k rows, I'm happy with the solution and does not need to check how it performs beyond that.
Thanks Reti43, much appreciated!